# How do I earn the 'Sniper Duel' achievement in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, achievements

I am attempting to earn the 'Sniper Duel' achievement. I have killed at least 4 skeletons, 50 blocks above them, and yet I haven't earned the achievement yet.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 7):

The achievement is actually 50 blocks away, horizontally.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sniper_Duel)